# Downloading big files and writing it locally

Tags: php

which is the best way to download from php large files without consuming all server's memory?

I could do this (bad code):

```
$url='http://server/bigfile';
$cont = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents('./localfile',$cont);
```

This example loads entry remote file in `$cont` and this could exceed memory limit.

Is there a safe function (maybe built-in) to do this (maybe stream_*)?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000483/php-how-download-big-file-using-php-low-memory-usage

Comment: answers on that Q aren't good

Comment: Yes they are. The accepted answer (poster used fsockopen) is one valid solution for that type of thing in PHP. Not because you don't think the answers aren't good that it justifies creating a duplicate of a question. You have enough rep, why not start a bounty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use curl and the option CURLOPT_FILE to save the downloaded content directly to a file.

```
set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen ('file', 'w+b');
$ch = curl_init('http://remote_url/file');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 75);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: why do you set timeout and returntransfer? ([source](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php))

Comment: @yes123 actually you are right RETURNTRANSFER is probably not necessary.  I put the timeout there for reference, it may be worth using it if you don't want your script to run forever.  (Ie. maybe the network speed is slower than expected).  There may be a default value for that is too low for your transfer time as well.  So it may be worthwhile setting that to a high value or 0.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function I use when downloading large files. It will avoid loading the entire file into the buffer. Instead, it will write to the destination as it receives the bytes.

```
function download($file_source, $file_target) 
{
    $rh = fopen($file_source, 'rb');
    $wh = fopen($file_target, 'wb');
    if (!$rh || !$wh) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($rh)) {
        if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 1024)) === FALSE) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    fclose($rh);
    fclose($wh);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good function. At this point the choice is between a function like this or using curl direct stream write

Comment: The difference is cURL will load the entire file into memory prior to writing (unless my memory has betrayed me).

Comment: HM i don't think.. with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);` you can avoid memory usage

Comment: I'm curious why you accepted the cURL solution when it does not address your primary concern, i.e., uses more memory. *Shrug*

Comment: Read my comment above. If you set `CURLOPT_FILE` you are avoiding memory usage