# Downloading a large file using curl

Tags: php, curl, download

I need to download remote file using curl.

Here's the sample code I have:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$st = curl_exec($ch);
$fd = fopen($tmp_name, 'w');
fwrite($fd, $st);
fclose($fd);

curl_close($ch);
```

But it can't handle big files, because it reads to memory first.

Is it possible to stream the file directly to disk?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
//This is the file where we save the    information
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');
//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));
// make sure to set timeout to a high enough value
// if this is too low the download will be interrupted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
// write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// get curl response
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you actually need to manually `fwrite` the data since you're using `CURLOPT_FILE`.

Comment: As @SashaChedygov has pointed out above, you don't need to use `fwrite` AND `CURLOPT_FILE`. Passing the `$fp` is enough. I did both and ended up with `1` at the end of content in the file.

Comment: It appears that setting CURLOPT_FILE before setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER doesn't work, presumably because CURLOPT_FILE depends on CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER being set. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99082

Comment: @paperclip I was having the same problem with the `1` added at the end of file. In my case I removed the `CURLOPT_FILE` statement and manually saved the file with `fwrite`. Just wanted to add that **BOTH** options are feasible (but we should use **just ONE of them**).

Comment: This solution doesn't work on HTTPS,
You should add :
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: @DonovanP No you shouldn't, If you need to add this it just means your certificate is invalid and you're using https wrong

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason the hosting didn't allow me to upload a large file.

Answer (score 28):

I use this handy function:

By downloading it with a 4094 byte step it will not full your memory

```
function download($file_source, $file_target) {
    $rh = fopen($file_source, 'rb');
    $wh = fopen($file_target, 'w+b');
    if (!$rh || !$wh) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($rh)) {
        if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 4096)) === FALSE) {
            return false;
        }
        echo ' ';
        flush();
    }

    fclose($rh);
    fclose($wh);

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
     $result = download('http://url','path/local/file');
```

You can then check if everything is ok with:

```
     if (!$result)
         throw new Exception('Download error...');
```

Comment: @Severus you catch http error as `fopen()` returning false and timeout you put it in the while loop (call `time()` and do the math)

Comment: cURL already has working implementation of this (see the accepted answer), why would you want implement something on your own?

Comment: Because cURL procedural interface is pretty bad

Comment: for what it's worth, I've been using `stream_copy_to_stream` instead of manually copying contents, makes a shorter code. Neither this nor that works with `https` (unless you stipulate a `$context`). Concerting procedural style - file functions aren't quite OOP too, and if you put curl options in an array, it'll look way cleaner anyway.

Comment: I tested it with a https, works great!!!, Thanks for you help @dynamic.

Answer (score 7):

Find below code if you want to download the contents of the specified URL also want to saves it to a file.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
/**
* Set the URL of the page or file to download.
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&topic=t&output=rss');

$fp = fopen('rss.xml', 'w+');
/**
* Ask cURL to write the contents to a file
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

If you want to downloads file from the FTP server you can use php FTP extension. Please find below code:

```
<?php
$SERVER_ADDRESS="";
$SERVER_USERNAME="";
$SERVER_PASSWORD="";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($SERVER_ADDRESS);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $SERVER_USERNAME, $SERVER_PASSWORD);

$server_file="test.pdf" //FTP server file path 
$local_file = "new.pdf"; //Local server file path 

##----- DOWNLOAD $SERVER_FILE AND SAVE TO $LOCAL_FILE--------##
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

when `curl` is used to download a large file then `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` is the main option you have to set for.

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` has to be true in case you are getting file like pdf/csv/image etc.

You may find the further detail over here(correct url) [Curl Doc](http://prashantpandeytech.blogspot.com/2012/10/understanding-curl-basics.html)

From that page:

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); //set timeout to 5 mins

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // true to get the output as string otherwise false
```

Comment: u can also go through the blog example regarding file download with curl [understanding curl basics](http://prashantpandeytech.blogspot.in/2012/10/there-is-common-problem-when-large-site.html)

Comment: This writes the file to memory first which is what the OP was specifically trying to avoid. That said, setting CURLOPT_TIMEOUT *is very important* as the process will timeout in the midst of receiving data once that time is hit.

Comment: For those who are googling this question after 2023 – the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is depreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function, which creates a tempfile in the filesystem and returns the path to the downloaded file if everything worked fine:

```
function getFileContents($url)
{
    // Workaround: Save temp file
    $img = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'pdf-');
    $img .= '.' . pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $fp = fopen($img, 'w+');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    fclose($fp);

    return $result ? $img : false;
}
```