# Copy file from remote URL to my server

Tags: php, curl, copy

I have this code and it works but has a limitation only can copy files of 4.0mb, someone can help me to increase that size to copy files larger. thanks

```
<? 
  $archivo_origen=$_POST["origen"]; 
  $archivo_destino=$_POST["destino"];

  function descarga_archivo ($archivo_origen,$archivo_destino){ 
    $mi_curl = curl_init ($archivo_origen);  
    $fs_archivo = fopen ($archivo_destino, "w");  
    curl_setopt ($mi_curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fs_archivo);  
    curl_setopt ($mi_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
    curl_exec ($mi_curl);  
    curl_close ($mi_curl);  
    fclose ($fs_archivo);  
  } 
  descarga_archivo($archivo_origen,$archivo_destino);
    header("location: index.php");


 ?>
```

Comment: Instead of using CURL, you might try [`file_get_contents($url)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)?

Comment: This seems to be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl

Comment: the problem is that this code runs on a free hosting server and I not have all the features enabled, so I use cURL, however would appreciate an example of file_get_contents ($ url) to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fs_origen = fopen($archivo_origen, 'r');
$fs_destino = fopen($archivo_destino, 'w');
while($data = fread($fs_origen, 4096)) fwrite($fs_destino, $data);
fclose($fs_origen);
fclose($fs_destino);
```

EDIT: replace `stream_copy_to_stream` with loop.

Comment: with all the codes that I can use just copy 4.0mb, I do not know if it will be by the server configuration

Comment: It sounds like both curl and stream_copy_to_stream run into php memory size limits. You may have to write your own loop using fread() and fwrite() in smaller chunks.

Comment: if you could give me an example, I do not know much about php. Use this code to download files that are denied because I am from Cuba and my proxy does not allow downloading files *. exe, *. zip  Thanks

Comment: thanks for the help but I think due to some configuration of my hosting, only copy 4.0mb. Thanks for your time

Comment: Sounds like the hosting server has a file size limit. They probably don't want you filling up their disk with junk, or using it to host lots of illegal downloads.