# How to send a file from one Yii controller to another Yii controller

Tags: yii

I want to transfer files between web applications.
Let's say application A is like a file server.
Application B is the user.

From time to time, application B will need to update its scripts. And it will get the updated scripts from application B.

Is it possible for a Yii controller in application A to read a file and send it to application B?

I imagine that I can use fopen to open a URL and get a file.
But how to make a controller return a file?

Comment: @Ninad, what I have tried is I use a public temporary folder on B. So A can get it using fopen and fwrite it to replace an old script on A. I think this way is not secure. I think transmitting between controllers is more secure.

Comment: Are application A and B on different servers?

Comment: If you want to develop on B and commit on A(production?) then use rsync. If you want to load scripts for A from B - import them in config. If you want to input changes to A in web - make model to work with files and try CMap::mergeArray.

Comment: @ineersa, I am imagining something like Norton's self update. Or like Glassfish's update mechanism.

Comment: @ethan, yes, they are on different server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess what I would do is set up an action in a controller in Application A, that reads and outputs the files you want Application B to download.  See here for examples on how to do that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

In Application B I would, personally, use CURL to download the files, as I could pass a username and password to Applicaton A to restrict the downloads.  This link offers some examples on to create a CURL request that downloads a file [Downloading a large file using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl).

To download multiple files you'd probably need to do one of two things: 1) Loop through an array of filenames in Application B that correspond with the files in Application A you want to download, or 2) Zip up the files in Application A, and then unpack them once downloaded by Application B http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php.