# Download zip PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a zip file (I don't know size and name before) with a request xml that return me a zip file. I want to download it but sometimes download it all (16mb about) sometimees not( 2mb or 4 mb or 1mb) I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
$ch2=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $this->URL);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5040);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$this->XMLRequest);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$xml = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);
$file2 = fopen('upload/item.zip','w+');
fwrite($file2, $xml);
fclose($file2);
```

I have also tried:

```
file_put_contents('upload/item.zip', $xml);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I dont see curl_exec in your code? is it $xml = curl_exec( $ch2 );

Comment: edit question i have missing a line @Dexa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`CURLOPT_FILE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to [download large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl)?

```
set_time_limit(0); //prevent timeout

$ch2=curl_init();
$file2 = fopen('upload/item.zip','w+');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $this->URL);

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FILE, $file2); //auto write to file

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5040);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$this->XMLRequest);
# don't use this. please verify your host & peer properly :)
# curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
# curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);
fclose($file2);
```

**EDIT:**

Notes: As pointed out by @bansi, you might need to verify the file, file size, `curl_error`, etc.

Comment: I was just writing the same answer, you beat me for a second. Nice. +1

Comment: Also always check if there is any errors before you confirm the downloaded file is correct. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Not sure if you need to set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` hmm... and yes need to verify the file as well.

Comment: It could be the server is not responding you with the correct info? What's in your `XMLRequest`?

Comment: no is a right request it's an xml request standard, I have checked with other system if the request is fine and it works, only it doesn't save the file well..

Comment: Try setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to 0?

Comment: return me always a 0byte file and print me a lot of character coded I don't know which is the problem, the response of the curl is a zip file I know (the server after my xml request return me a zip file contains many xml insides)

Comment: Try removing `CURLOPT_HEADER` instead. I tried on my machine and it should work. See my edited answer

Comment: I don't know the problem, with my code in the answer I donwload a file but not total, with your method always 0byte... is very strange the problem... I don't know why I have this problem...

Comment: Oh my, so sorry, returntransfer shouldn't be set!! Remove `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

Comment: something is moved... 2,9 mb but if I try to extract return me error like that the file isn't complete.. it would be about 15mb.. but now isn't 0 byte, I have to complete the transfer of all file.. step by step :)

Comment: Do not specify CURLOPT_SSLVERSION anymore. Due to POODLE patches on servers, SSL3 will be blocked. Leave CURLOPT_SSLVERSION out completely for the server to auto-negotiate the secure connection.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: I know, years ago, but if someone also has the problem that only a part of the data is downloaded: GIVE MORE TIME! 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, (60*30)); // 30 minutes`
Also of course allow the script to run as long as it is.