# How to convert mp3 format data to mp3 file using php?

Tags: php, html5-audio, content-type, file-writing, php-curl

I am making PHP curl call and getting mp3 format raw data. How do i convert that raw data to mp3 file.
My code is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:audio/mpeg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$data=curl_exec ($ch);
```

I received raw data of mp3 format. i don't want to download that file in browser, i want to save that file in my server side. How do i convert that raw data to mp3 format file?

I tried normal php file writing but it not works. for example :

```
$myfile = fopen("D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\testfile.mp3", "w"); 
$fwrite($myfile, $data);
```

fopen returns false value and I could not create mp3 file using php file operation. How do i convert and save the mp3 file in server??. after saving that file i will give that path to audio tag src. `<audio src="D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\testfile.mp3" />`

my curl response like this:

ID3#TSSELavf56.15.102��8�Infora !#%*,.0357<>@BEGIMPRTVY[adfhjmqsuxz|~��������������������������������������������������Lavc56.13$a5Cwc��8�"#�p7I<��Z���<ѣF� ��HP���.uN{P�! �{�����������]�D�DDwww��������"'����_���";�������=��B""�������

Comment: Did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl

Comment: @Twisty thanks for reply but It also not worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You forget the binary transfer directive:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
```