# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, curl

Hello please how i can fix this error ?

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted

The problem I encounter is when I try to get a content of a big file from a website

my official code is :

```
<?php

//begin
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 8096);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://softnet.co.tz/cms/scripts/here.txt');

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$out = fopen('result.txt', 'a');
if ($out) {
    fwrite($out, $content);
    fclose($out);
}

?>
```

i've already read some stuff but didn't get it solved.
please help me.

Comment: Please do not abuse the snippet tool

Comment: If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Note that there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You're fetching a huge resource and storing it into a variable before flushing it into a file.

So, let's say that in your `php.ini` file you've the following memory limit configuration:

```
memory_limit = 24M
```

This means that you're limiting the amount of memory a PHP request can use to 24 Megabytes of main memory (25165824 bytes). So if the resource you're fetching and storing into variable `$content` exceeds this size, the request will fail with that error.

You can use cURL to write the resource content directly into a file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl#6409531). The relevant cURL option to do it is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
```

Note that `$out` is your file pointer, so you need to call `fopen()` before setting this option.

Comment: This answer is thorough and valid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of a similar error, I was POSTing a small amount of data to a remote server using the PHP Curl library. This "memory exhausted" error was caused by the remote server trying to write into a directory that didn't exist. When I created the directory, the error no longer occurred.