# Dropbox api file download and upload to s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, dropbox-api

im trying to download the file from dropbox using v2 api and upload it to amazon s3

to download file here is what i did:

```
$headers= array(
                        'Content-Type: ',
                        "Authorization: Bearer EkOrS5mbVAwA....",
                        "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/clients/erbrecht, kenneth/2nd dispute erbrecht.docx\"}");
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response  = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

the code above returned response in "application/octet-stream" i assume, so my first problem is to convert this stream to a file and upload it to s3

i have this code that takes physical path of the file and upload it to s3 but in the above case i have the stream

```
try{
        $s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
                                            'region'    =>  S3_REGION,
                                            'version'   => 'latest',
                                            'credentials' => array(
                                                'key' => S3_ACCESS_KEY,
                                                'secret'  => S3_SECRET_KEY,
                                              )
                                        ));



        $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket'    =>  $this->s3bucket,
            'Key'       =>  "uploads/{$name}",
            'Body'      =>  fopen($path,'rb'),
            'ACL'       =>  'public-read'
        ]);

            return '';
    }catch(S3Exception $e){
        //return $e->getMessage();
        return 'Error Uploading File, Please try again';
    }
```

so the problem is to convert stream to file and upload to s3, how can i change the above code to do that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`application/octet-stream`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream) doesn't mean "stream" in the sense that you're thinking.  It simply means that nature of the contents of the file are binary but otherwise of an unknown/uninteresting type, as far as the browser should care -- it shouldn't try to interpret the content, it should just allow the content to be saved to a file.  I could be mistaken, but I believe your actual question seems to be "how do I download with curl and save to a file so that I can upload that file to S3?"

Comment: yes correct i want the content to be converted to file so i can upload on s3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6409531/1695906

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot it worked! :)

Comment: I wish that close message didn't say "exact duplicate," but given that the solution in the other answer took care of the real issue at hand, I think the closure is probably appropriate.