# PHP issue with getting a redirect to work

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I'm trying to get a zip file to automatically download:

```
            $attachment_location =  "https://dev.com/daily/updates/com_prog_v1_8_0.zip";

            if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {

                header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
                header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for internet explorer
                header("Content-Type: application/zip");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
                header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=com_prog_v1_8_0.zip");
                readfile($attachment_location);
                die(); 

            }
```

I've tried to link in the browser and the file downloads without a problem.  I'm not sure what to do to debug it.  As far as I can tell it is right.  I'm expecting to run this file (and index.php file) and have it kick off the download of the file.  I've had a good look at the other posts and can't figure out the problem.

I've also tried just

```
            file_put_contents("com_prog_v1_8_0.zip", fopen("https://dev.com/daily/updates/com_prog_v1_8_0.zip", 'r'));
```

but that also throws

Error: File not found.

Any ideas what I can do to track down the problem would be great.  I'm sure it must be something I can't see for looking!

thansk

Comment: Use curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl

Comment: How are you redirecting?

Comment: hi  I tried curl but it doesn't work - same error

Comment: How are you redirecting?

Comment: I'm just using code above to get the file to download

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe file_exist() works with urls.  Try something like this instead:

```
function url_exists($url){
    $ccmd = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ccmd, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ccmd);
    $rtncode = curl_getinfo($ccmd, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ccmd);

    if($rtncode == 200){
       return true;
    }
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: I took out the if statement and the page gives a 500 error

Comment: Did you check the error log to see where the error came from?