# CURL in php returns a display text in my page

Tags: php, curl

Hi i have this curl to download link files from the sendthisfile.com. Now my problem is when I try to test it last week my code runs well. But now when I test it this is what I got to my web app. I suspect this is from the curl when processing the files. Can someone help me figured this thing out? this is my code below in curl

```
$zipUrl = "https://download.com/sample.zip";
$fileName = date().".zip"; //create a random name or certain kind of name here
                
                                  $fh = fopen($filename, 'w');
                                  $ch = curl_init();
                                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $zipUrl);
                                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh); 
                                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // this will follow redirects
                                  curl_exec($ch);
                                  curl_close($ch);
```

can someone help me why this throws a texts in a webpage?

[image: the is the screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You're missing this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

This tells curl to return the output instead of directly displaying it. It's also noteworthy that you should set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` before `CURLOPT_FILE` as I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl).

See the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information.

Comment: okay i will try this one adding CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Comment: do i need this? CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Comment: last week my code runs well now it throws a texts to webpage.

Comment: is it okay not to use this curl_exec ?

Comment: when i add CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER this file is not being extracted