# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in PHP

Tags: php, memory

I am facing issue in my code, when I am trying to store the file_get_contents output into an obj.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($obj);
```

I am not allowed to change the memory size in ini.php because it is on server.Any other solution for this.?

Comment: Please check this solution - it uses downloading the file piece by piece https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000483/how-download-big-file-using-php-low-memory-usage After that You can use `file_get_contents($local_file)` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple typo:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: Oops, yes that was a typo error while posting the question here. But I still have that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other options of increasing memory limit?
Like

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); //change the -1 to a value that acommodates to your use case
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

or set bigger memory