# server to server partial download

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, download

So I am trying to transfer/copy a large file from a remote server to my server in separate parts or chunks. I tried the script provided here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4000569/7559794
I made some changes and gave a form to the script and used AJAX to communicate with PHP script as follows: 
The index.html contains a form with POST method and a submit button that calls the following function OnClick:

```
<script>
function stratdown() {
     var partsizevalue = $('#psize').val();
     var dfilename = $('#dfile').val();
     var sfilename = $('#sfile').val();
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'trigger.php',
           data:{dfile: dfilename, sfile: sfilename, psize: partsizevalue}, //{value: a, cID: cID}
           success:function(result) {
             alert(result);
           }     
      });
}</script>
```

the file trigger.php contains the following script:

```
 <?php

require 'partdown.php';
$infile = $_POST["dfile"];
$outfile = $_POST["sfile"];
$partsize = $_POST["psize"];

echo $mesg = DownInParts::copyfile_chunked($infile, $outfile, $partsize);

?>
```

and the required partdown.php contains:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copy remote file over HTTP one small chunk at a time.
 *
 * @param $infile The full URL to the remote file
 * @param $outfile The path where to save the file
 */
 class DownInParts
{
    public function copyfile_chunked($infile, $outfile, $partsize) 
    {
    $chunksize = $partsize * 1024; // 10 Megs

    /**
     * parse_url breaks a part a URL into it's parts, i.e. host, path,
     * query string, etc.
     */
    $parts = parse_url($infile);
    $i_handle = fsockopen($parts['host'], 80, $errstr, $errcode, 5);
    $o_handle = fopen($outfile, 'wb');

    if ($i_handle == false || $o_handle == false) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
        $parts['path'] .= '?' . $parts['query'];
    }

    /**
     * Send the request to the server for the file
     */
    $request = "GET {$parts['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
    $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n";
    $request .= "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($i_handle, $request);

    /**
     * Now read the headers from the remote server. We'll need
     * to get the content length.
     */
    $headers = array();
    while(!feof($i_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($i_handle);
        if ($line == "\r\n") break;
        $headers[] = $line;
    }

    /**
     * Look for the Content-Length header, and get the size
     * of the remote file.
     */
    $length = 0;
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
            $length = (int)str_replace('Content-Length: ', '', $header);
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start reading in the remote file, and writing it to the
     * local file one chunk at a time.
     */
    $cnt = 0;
    while(!feof($i_handle)) {
        $buf = '';
        $buf = fread($i_handle, $chunksize);
        $bytes = fwrite($o_handle, $buf);
        if ($bytes == false) {
            return false;
        }
        $cnt += $bytes;

        /**
         * We're done reading when we've reached the content length
         */
        if ($cnt >= $length) break;
    }

    fclose($i_handle);
    fclose($o_handle);
    return $cnt;
    }
}
?>
```

I didn't manage to make it function. I have however tried to add the action "trigger.php" to the form in order to call PHP directly yet The file I downloaded was (0 Kb) in size. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just missed adding this two line in the  < head > section due to stress.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This did the trick for me. Now I need a progress bar and a success alert.