# PHP creating personal directories for each user

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm working in php and want to make directories for each user where I would store their uploaded images. Only the user can access his/her directory and respective images.

I couldn't find much documentation on how to do this, namely creating directories, best place to put them in my server, how to link them to a user, and setting them to private. Please share your guidance on where to start. What is the standard practice?

Comment: "Only the user can access his/her directory and respective files" are you asking how to create a cloud storage system such as dropbox?

Comment: @Paul no it isn't for a storage application but I'll probably have to implement similar functions just much more basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to put Files with restricted access outside the public webroot folder and serve them via PHP, which will enable you to check the users credentials before.
(see [Fastest Way to Serve a File Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697748/fastest-way-to-serve-a-file-using-php))

That way you might not need one directory per user.