# How to download contents from server to download folder?

Tags: php, imap

I will get the content in $attachments['attachment'].It simply saved the files in the same location as the script using fopen and fwrite which just moves the content . I want the content to be downloaded as normal download. I have referred many site but its of no use. Anyone kindly help me??

```
<?php
set_time_limit(3000); 
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'YOUR_GMAIL_USERNAME'; # e.g somebody@gmail.com
$password = 'YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect   to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
$max_emails = 16;
if($emails) {
$count = 1;
rsort($emails);
foreach($emails as $email_number) 
{
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);
    $attachments = array();
    if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
        {
            $attachments[$i] = array(
                'is_attachment' => false,
                'filename' => '',
                'name' => '',
                'attachment' => ''
            );

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
            {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
            {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
            {
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                { 
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] =    base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
                /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                { 
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
    foreach($attachments as $attachment)
    {
        if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
        {
            $filename = $attachment['name'];
            if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

            if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

            /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
             * have the attachment with the same file name.
             */
            **$fp = fopen($email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
            fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);**
            fclose($fp);
        }

    }

    if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;
}

} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

echo "Done";

?>
```

Comment: Describe in more details what you exactly want.

Comment: i want to make the download to pc downloads folder

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: it works there is no problem... i will get attachment from gmail in $attachment['attachment'] which gets download to the page location....what i want is to make the download to local downloads folder...

Comment: If your php can get acces to your download folder you can `fwrite` to this folder.

Comment: I already used fwrite only i dono how to fwrite to this folder. Can you help me????

Comment: Is your php server have an acces to folder where you want to put files?

Comment: I am only getting the content of the image from the server not the url which i move to the folder using fwrite. I want to download this content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem.
You need just to change line

```
$filename = $attachment['name'];
```

to

```
$filename = "/home/myuser/downloads/" . $attachment['name'];
```

Or am I missing the point?
Please explain more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [move-uploaded-file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function. It does exactly what you wrotte.

Comment: i am developing this code for a mailbox where user's mail will be displayed.The code above fetches the attachment from mail which is downloaded to the same location as the script. As you said move-uploaded-file function cannot be used, for that the content should be downloaded to the database then only it can be moved. I want the content to be downloaded directly to the users computer. Any idea????

Comment: Just to understand: You want to run a script on the `Host`, and then save a file on the `Client`? If so, then it should not be possible. If what you want is to offer some sort of link, then use PHP to output a binary file ([chek here how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697748/fastest-way-to-serve-a-file-using-php))