# Image access monitoring

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to monitor image access by user. My website is having few images. But I want to run particular script on access of image by user if user access image directly , e.g

```
 http:www.website.com/images/image1.jpg
```

if user directly put above link in browser then script should run. Is there any way ?

Comment: why not check the referrer from Javascript(document.refereer).If they are coming from one sest of the places--->run the script else dont run..

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite all access to images/* to a script and serve the file over the script using mod_rewrite. In the script you can then -beofre sending the file - make a call to the db or something...

[Url Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

[Serving files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432713/serving-large-files-with-php)

Example htacces:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*) getImage.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use php but in any web frameworks you should be able to do URL dispatching (such as using regex to route any *.jpg access), log it and then redirect it to the real image by setting in header MIME type to be 'image/jpeg' and serving the actual image file.